# Qt compiling with msvc10 toolchain always spend the same time to compile, Any trick to improve?

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-optimization

Before, I used Mingw. I have the impression that little changes, in example, a simple line feed on my code, does not affect to the compiling process. That is, in this example, the compile process was very fast. (It is as the classes doesn't changed does not be recompiled..? )
Now with msvc10 toolchain, I always spend the same time when compile. A little change (the same line feed), means a slow compile process (as every class where recompiled ?... )

I'm not an expert with compiler issues, so I have no idea what is happen. 
Any idea, tip or trick ? Thanks

Comment: Are precompiled headers used?

Comment: No. But before (with mingw) I don't use pre.

Comment: precompiled headers are exactly for such stuff - platfowm SDK headers, Qt, whetever third party headers you depend on. They are pre-compiled and that saves a lot of time.

Comment: What is the timestamp of your source files? Sounds like the timestamp of your source files are in the future, causing MSVC to think that the source files are newer than the object files.

Comment: I see how I have a lot of obj's are not modified (so the timestamp is not a problem). Only a 3% of my project files are recompiled. ... So I dont understand why is thre reason to spend a significant time to create 3 o 4 new obj's.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Qt compiles with /MP, which means minimal rebuild is disabled. You might want to change that.

Comment: This a qmake option , isnt't . I have NO options at my project settings ( i have only -r -spec win32-msvc2010 ). Thanks